# Using [self method] or @selector(method)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can anyone enlighten me as to the differences between the two statements below.

```
[self playButtonSound];
```

AND:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(playButtonSound)];
```

I am just asking as I had some old code that used `@selector`, now with a little more knowledge I can't think why I did not use `[self playButtonSound]` instead, they both seem to do the same as written here.

gary

Comment: Van: why did you delete, this is helpful is it not? 

They definitely will do the same thing. A small difference is that the first example will be sending one message, playButtonSound; the second will be sending two messages, first performSelector:, which will then send playButtonSound. I would always go for the first option unless you have no choice, if only for readability.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both to the same thing, but `[self playButtonSound];` is definitely the normal way to invoke a method in Objective-C. However, using `performSelector:` allows you to call a method that is only determined at runtime.

From the [NSObject Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:):

> The `performSelector`: method is
>   equivalent to sending an `aSelector`
>   message directly to the receiver. For
>   example, all three of the following
>   messages do the same thing:
>
> ```
> id myClone = [anObject copy];
> id myClone = [anObject performSelector:@selector(copy)];
> id myClone = [anObject performSelector:sel_getUid("copy")];
> ```
>
> However, the `performSelector:` method
>   allows you to send messages that
>   aren’t determined until runtime. A
>   variable selector can be passed as the
>   argument:
>
> ```
> SEL myMethod = findTheAppropriateSelectorForTheCurrentSituation();
> [anObject performSelector:myMethod];
> ```

Answer (score 6):

```
[self playButtonSound];
```

Here compiler will check if your object responds to `-playButtonSound` message and will give you a warning if it does not.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(playButtonSound)];
```

Calling `-playButtonSound` this way you will not get compiler warning. However you can check dynamically if objects responds to a given selector - so you can safely attempt to call arbitrary selector on a object without specifying its type and not getting compiler warnings (that may be useful for example for calling optional methods in a objects delegate):

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(playButtonSound)])
  [self performSelector:@selector(playButtonSound)];
```

Comment: There's a missing bracket in the line `if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(playButtonSound)]`—it should be `if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(playButtonSound)])`.

Comment: Actually, you can have the compiler throw a warning at undeclared selectors by adding -Wundeclared-selector in the Other Warning Flags field in your build settings.  I find this to be pretty helpful.