# Difference between [self MethodName] and [self performSelector:@selector(Method Name)]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, methods

What is the difference between calling the methods with following types

1.

```
[self methodName];
```

and

2.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodName)];   // no afterDelay is used
```

Is it like performSelector will use different thread to work??

Comment: Possible duplicate thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674827/using-self-method-or-selectormethod

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In most cases, they are equivalent.

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector%3a), the purpose of the `performSelector:` variant is so that you can call methods that are defined dynamically and not actually present at compile-time.  That's all.  For calling a method that *is* present at compile-time, there is no difference between the two.