# Ios Swift programatically change view order over storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, storyboard

I have a textView and an imageView added in storyboard as shown in the screenshot below.

**In story board order is:**

- `textView`
- `imageView`

Now in run `imageView` covers `textView` and things assigned to `textView` does not work.

**So I programmatically want to change the order to:**

- `imageView`
- `textView`

(Without touching storyboard)

I tried:

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(textView)

self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
```

and

```
imageView.layer.zPosition = 1
textView.layer.zPosition = 2
```

None of these is working for me

[image: Story Board View order]

Comment: have you tried making the imageView hidden to check if textView is in the right place?

Comment: Yes, Its in the right place, I have tried all those. If i change the order in storyboard, it works, but not able to do programatically.

Comment: You can specify where you use your code? `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(textView)

self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)`

Comment: @ReinierMelian regardless of where the code is being executed it has to bring the textView to the front, right?

Comment: Right but maybe when your code is executed, this views aren't there @MohsenShakiba

Comment: @ReinierMelian In viewDidLoad, views are all available to use, just not drawn yet, so if you change the zIndex, they should be drawn properly

Comment: yes I agree but, you know where @SujayUN put his code?

Comment: I have tried both inside viewDidLoad and inside button click function

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is you might be using these codes in `viewDidLoad` method. Try using in `viewDidAppear`

Or another try is using `performSelector`

write this in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`

```
self.performSelector(#selector(changeOrder), withObject: nil, afterDelay: 0.2)
```

and write your order changing in this function

```
func changeOrder() {
   imageView.layer.zPosition = 1
   textView.layer.zPosition = 2
}
```

**Edit**

I have made a sample. Have a look.
https://github.com/RajanMaheshwari/OrderingLayer

I have tried the code and its working fine

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.performSelector(#selector(changeOrder), withObject: nil, afterDelay: 0.2)
}

    func changeOrder() {

        myImageView.layer.zPosition = 1
        myTextField.layer.zPosition = 2
    }
}
```

My Storyboard

[image]

My Final Outcome after running the code

[image]

Now `imageView` is on layer 1 and `textField` is on layer 2 position

If you comment out the `performSelector` line then the outcome will be

[image]

Here the `imageView` is on layer 2 position and `textField` is on layer 1 position.

Comment: viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear wouldn't be any different from viewDidLoad for this code

Comment: @MohsenShakiba You might try `viewDidAppear` then. Point is not did or willappear, point is the perform selector which are called at run time dynamically

Comment: @MohsenShakiba See this for more details.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445337/difference-between-self-methodname-and-self-performselectorselectormethod
And this works for me.

Comment: @MohsenShakiba See the sample and read more about `performSelector`. I have mentioned the github link

Comment: Again it's not about did load or appear. It's about dynamic run time calling with performSelector